# Reliable way to count total used space of firebase storage per user

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm trying to figure out an approach that will guarantee correct count of user uploaded file size from a web client to the firebase storage.

The core requirements are these:

- it must be **stable**: it must guarantee to count every uploaded file
- it must be **scalable**: I can't read "all stored files" to calculate size at once as the number of files can be huge
- it must be **secure**: I can't rely on browser, the calculations must be performed on server.

So far the approach is this:

1. user of my web app can upload multiple files
2. those files are uploaded using firebase web client sdk
3. on the server I listen to `functions.storage.object().onFinalize()` to get file size for each file
4. then I update a dedicated document in firestore to add the new size to the total (let's call it `totalStorageSizeDoc`)

This approach addresses security and scalability but the problem that I see here is when user is uploading a bunch of small enough files, this can easily trigger lots of `functions.storage.object().onFinalize()` within 1 second, which is 'not-hard-but-still' a limit for write operations in firestore. At this point the writes to `totalStorageSizeDoc` will also be performed too fast with the risk of rejecting some of those writes.

Is there a way to easily queue the writes from the `onFinalize()` to ensure the `totalStorageSizeDoc` is not overwhelmed? Or should I take a completely different approach? Maybe there are any best-practices out there to count the used storage size that I've missed?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to [enable retries](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries) for your function, so that if it fails for whatever reason (like exceeding some limit), then the system will simply retry it until it succeeds.

Comment: btw, anyway to do that programmatically as of now?

Comment: With the Firebase CLI, no.